# WM_DRAWITEM get called only when mouse is in dialog window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, win32gui

I'm working on a themed ownerdraw button using Win32 native.
Following a tutorial and a sample project on another website, I got my button almost perfect(almost without bug), but there's one which left, and I have a issue in fixing it.

Basically, I'm subclassing using SetWindowLongPtr API the window of the button, and from there, when WM_LBUTTONUP is catched, I would need to call DrawThemeBackground for reset the state of the button, OR, just handle again WM_DRAWITEM. The problem is that WM_DRAWITEM is getting called only when my mouse is on the dialog window, which is not really a problem, if there would be a way for advice the main dialog to handle it when I want it. I tried with InvalidateRect, but it is not making WM_DRAWITEM, but WM_CTLCOLORBTN.

So, my question is: 
Is there any way for let WM_DRAWITEM being handled even if the mouse is out of the dialog 
OR
Is there any way for advice the main dialog that it should handle again WM_DRAWITEM, evne if the mouse is out of the dialog?

Thanks alot for taking your time in replyng me.

Comment: `WM_DRAWITEM` is sent to the button's parent window, not to the button itself. You need to subclass the button's parent window to handle the message. When you need to refresh the drawing, `InvalidateRect()` will trigger a repaint. If that is not working, then you are doing something wrong. Please show your actual code.

Comment: I'm using the same code as this example:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/buttonctrl/advancedbuttons/article.php/c5161/Native-Win32-ThemeAware-OwnerDraw-Controls-No-MFC.htm

The WM_DRAWITEM is being called on the parent window(so the main dialog proc). Yes, there is being subclassed the button and from the subclass dialog proc is being called InvalidateRect, but it doesn't make WM_DRAWITEM message being called again.

Comment: Please show the actual code you are actually using in your project, don't just link to someone else's code. For all we know, you could have copied that code into your project wrong.

Comment: Sorry, thats the code I'm using(copy and pasted it from main.cpp, I did the pastebin): http://pastebin.com/CG1xyyxv
In ButtWindProc you can notice that in WM_LBUTTONUP I'm calling InvalidateRect, but as I already said, no WM_DRAWITEM is being getting executed inside the main dlg proc, but it gets executed only when my mouse is inside the main dialog.